# jquery auto-suggestion example doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This might be very easy for some of you but very hard for me since first time doing it.

By looking at some examples on the web, I ended up with the code below for auto-suggestion example but the code doesn't work.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#textbox_postcode').autocomplete(
            {
                source: 'search-db.php',
                minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="textbox_postcode" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

> $keyword = ltrim(strtolower(strip_tags($_GET['keyword'])));
>
> if (! $keyword) return;
>
> $host =
>   'localhost'; $user    = 'root'; $pswd = ''; $dtbs = 'geomaps';
>
> $host_conn    = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd); $dtbs_conn    =
>   mysql_select_db($dtbs);
>
> $return = array();
>
> $sql = "SELECT id, postcode FROM postcodes WHERE postcode LIKE
>   '$keyword%' ORDER BY postcode"; $run = mysql_query($sql);
>
> if (@mysql_num_rows($run) == 0) return;
>
> while ($records = mysql_fetch_array($run, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {     $return[] =
>   $records; }
>
> echo json_encode($return);

Comment: When I first load the page I get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'`. When I type something, nothing happens.

Comment: isn't autocomplete in jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, it is.  So at the very least he needs to include the jQuery UI js and css files.

Comment: Ok I added `jquery-ui.css`, `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` to my html. I changed `echo json_encode($return);` with `return json_encode($return);` (same with echo). Error is gone but I still cannot get the result from database. Any idea?

Comment: keep the echo json_encode($return). Does the PHP page print the JSON object?

Comment: OK I kept `echo`. Direct test in `search-db.php` prints this one: `["ABC111","ABC222","ABC333"]` as jQuery wants.

Comment: When I changed `source: 'search-db.php'` to `source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]` it works. Why my return is not accepted?

Comment: Do you have a live version we can check?

Comment: is search-db.php in different folder?

Comment: what php version? (json_encode PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$_GET['keyword']` to `$_GET['term']`

Comment: I checked thedocs, and it appends 'term' to the URL not 'keyword'. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ scroll down to the bottom and you will see that it uses 'term'.