# Can't make autocomplete work with ajax + jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to accomplish autocomplete task with the help of ajax (jQuery). Lets have a look at scripts

here is html =>

```
<input type="text" name="user_key" id="user_key">
```

here is javascript in the same file =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#user_key").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response){
            var suggestions = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax/autocomplete.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {user_key:$(this).val()},
                success: function(result){
                    $.each(result,function(i,val){
                        suggestions.push(val.name);
                    });
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
            response(suggestions);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is php script from autocomplete.php file =>

```
if (!$connection->connect_errno){
        if ($connection->set_charset("utf8")){
            if ($r = $connection->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE '" . $_POST['user_key'] . "%'")){
                for ($x=0,$numrows = $r->num_rows;$x<$numrows;$x++){
                    if ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                        $array[$x] = array("name",$row['name']);
                    }
                }
                $r->free();
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
```

PS. It doesn't work. Please help , I've been trying to accomplish this task for the past 2 days,but can't get it to work. Thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Considering you have already included jquery library, if you are looking in firefox check error console Control+Shift+J, check what exact error you are getting.

Comment: What does the AJAX request return?

Comment: @Tjkoopa what do you mean ? I'm trying to retrieve information (usernames) from mysql database onkeyup in autocomplete form

Comment: Yes, what is the response of that request? You should be able to see it in the console. Is it actually returning the correct JSON as expected?

Comment: autocomplete.php returns value like that => `[["name","one"],["name","two"],["name","three"]]` and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[$x] = array("name",$row['name']);
```

this is making name and the value from the database both as the elements of the array()

change the code of autocomplete.php to

```
if (!$connection->connect_errno){
        if ($connection->set_charset("utf8")){
            if ($r = $connection->query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE '" . $_POST['user_key'] . "%'")){
                for ($x=0,$numrows = $r->num_rows;$x<$numrows;$x++){
                    if ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                        $array[$x] = array("name"=>$row['name']);
                    }
                }
                $r->free();
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
```

This will make name as the key for the value fetched from the database

this will help you.

Comment: what is changed in your code ? what is difference between mine and yours ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take another look at the autocomplete docs but you will be able to find an answer here: [jquery auto-suggestion example doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743625/jquery-auto-suggestion-example-doesnt-work/11744644#11744644)